# OpenSSL RSA decryption failed

Tags: php, c, encryption, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to encrypt data with RSA in a C program, that I send with POST method on my server and then decrypt it in PHP. For both program I use OpenSSL to encrypt / decrypt the data.

I have the error *"error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error"* during the decryption in PHP and no data is return by the *openssl_private_decrypt* function.

Here is my C program :

```
RSA *createRSA(unsigned char *key, int public)
{
    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
    BIO *keybio;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key,  -1);
    if (keybio == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (public)
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    else
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    return rsa;
}

char *rsa_encode(char *json)
{
    char *data;
    RSA *rsa;
    int encrypted_length = 0;
    char pub[] = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY"; //RSA public key of size 8192
          
    rsa  = createRSA((unsigned char *)pub, 1);
    if (!(data = malloc(RSA_size(rsa))))
        exit(0);
    encrypted_length = RSA_public_encrypt((int)strlen(json), (unsigned char *)json, (unsigned char *)data, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    RSA_free(rsa);
    if (encrypted_length > 0)
        return data;
    return NULL;
}

char *bin2hex(const unsigned char *key, int size)
{
    char *hex;
    int i = 0;
    if (!(hex = malloc((size * 2 + 1) * sizeof(char))))
        handleError();
    while (i < size)
    {
        sprintf((char *)(hex + (i * 2)),"%02x", key[i]);
        i++;
    }
    hex[i * 2] = '\0';
    return hex;
}
```

Here is my PHP program :

```
$hexa = $_POST["data"];
$data = hexToStr($hexa);
$privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey("file://private.pem");
$decrypted = "";
$ret = openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted, $privateKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
echo openssl_error_string() . "\n";
```

I don't understand where is the error, for both program I use *OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING* so why OpenSSL error tell me that the error is on my padding ?

Comment: A padding error is usually a symptom of some other underlying errors. If your data don't decrypt correctly your padding will be invalid, giving you this error. You need to verify that every single parameter is correct.

Comment: In your PHP script, the first argument that you are passing to `openssl_private_decrypt` is `$data`,  But, how is a value being assigned to `$data`?

Comment: Thanks for your help ! So the problem should come from data or privateKey, but how can I know with more precision which value is the source of the problem and why @EbbeM.Pedersen ?

Comment: Thanks for your help @mti2935 ! In my php script I get `$data` with : `$data = hexToStr($hexa);`  just after `$hexa = $_POST["data"];` . I think I remove it accidentally in the post but it's in my code.

Comment: @Hdb770 OK, that makes sense.  But hexToStr is not a built-in PHP function.  Do you mean hex2bin?  In order for the crypto in your C program and your PHP program to be interoperable, you need to pass the inputs to these crypto functions as bytes on both sides (and the outputs of these functions are bytes as well).  To transport payloads between the two, it's ok to convert bytes to hex on the sending side, then transport the hex, then convert hex back to bytes on the receiving side.  But, the important thing is to make sure that you are always working in bytes with the crypto functions.

Comment: @mti2935 `hexToStr` was a function that I code. As you told me, I replaced it by `hex2bin` but I got the same result. So this is my code : I get my encrypted data, I convert into hex in C, then I send it to my server and use `hex2bin` to decode it (so it should be bytes) and put it into `openssl_private_decrypt` but I got an error again.. For information, my `openssl_get_privatekey` don't return false so I guess problem is in `$data` as you suggest.

Comment: If it's a problem with "data" it will show up when you print the data on C- and PHP-side in hex representation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found why decryption didn't work.
I was using this line to encode in hexa in C :
`encoded = bin2hex(data, (int)strlen((char *)data);`

data (the encrypted data) is `unsigned char *` and can contain null bytes. But I was using `strlen` which stop on first null byte. So my encrypted data was truncated when it was sended on server.

So the solution is to use the length of data that is given in return value of `len = RSA_public_encrypt((int)strlen((char *)src), src, encrypted, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);` instead of `(int)strlen((char *)data);`

Thanks you all for your help !